# why can't I get my jquery to fade in on click of button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fadein, fade

```css
#rock {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 49.4%
}

#paper {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 49%;
  bottom: 81px;
}

#scissors {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 48.14%;
  bottom: 162px;
}

#shoot {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 48.7%;
  bottom: 243px;
}
```

I'm trying to get these h2 elements to fade in then out one after the other after the click of one of three buttons, but my JQuery isn't working for the fade in portion (I'm trying to take this in pieces since I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery). Here's my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#rock").fadeIn();
    $("#paper").fadeIn();
    $("#scissors").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#shoot").fadeIn(3000);
  });
});
```

```html
    <div class="selections">
      <button class="selection" data-selection="rock">&#128507;</button>
      <button class="selection" data-selection="paper"></button>
      <button class="selection" data-selection="scissors">&#9986;</button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="chant" id="rock">Rock</h2>
    <h2 class="chant" id="paper">Paper</h2>
    <h2 class="chant" id=scissors>Scissors</h2>
    <h2 class="chant" id="shoot">Shoot!</h2>
```

`

Comment: Your code should already fade those elements in correctly. Just remember, for a fade-in to actually have any effect at all, it has to actually be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your initial goal, everything is fine except: You need to hide your `h2`'s initially, which you can do with the `hidden` attribute.

I'll probably get in trouble for this, but I thought I would show one way to complete this game. The code is commented below.
If you want to only reveal the associate button h2, access the `data()` of that element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']; // our choices
  $("button").click(function() {
    $('.chant').hide(); // hide all h2s for the round
    $("#" + $(this).data("selection")).fadeIn(); // my selection - $(this).data("selection") grabs the data-selection attribute of the button ( $(this) ) which was clicked 
    let computer = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]; // a random computer choice
    $("#computer").html(computer.toUpperCase()).fadeIn("slow"); // new element #computer takes random value as html and fades in

    // our chooser logic - we compare the index positions of the 2 choices
    let msg, diff = choices.indexOf($(this).data("selection")) - choices.indexOf(computer);
    if (diff === 0) msg = "Its a Tie";
    else if (diff > 0 || diff === -2) msg = "You Won!";
    else msg = "Shoot!";
    $("#shoot").html(msg).fadeIn(3000);
    // $("#paper").fadeIn();
    // $("#scissors").fadeIn("slow");
    // $("#shoot").fadeIn(3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selections">
  <button class="selection" data-selection="rock">&#128507;</button>
  <button class="selection" data-selection="paper"></button>
  <button class="selection" data-selection="scissors">&#9986;</button>
</div>
<h2 class="chant" hidden id="rock">Rock</h2>
<h2 class="chant" hidden id="paper">Paper</h2>
<h2 class="chant" hidden id="scissors">Scissors</h2>
<h2 class="chant" hidden id="computer"></h2>
<h2 class="chant" hidden id="shoot">Shoot!</h2>
```

Comment: I have an idea... might be `$("#" + $(this).data("selection")).fadeIn();` could be explained a bit, as @Alx_Wil95 says `I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to start them `display:none`. Instead you could just start them without text and then `.hide()` them and set the `.text()` right before they `.fadeIn()`.

I kind of went with the other answer and assumed you're trying to make a game. Didn't realize you can make hours of fun in so few lines of code.

```js
$('.selections button').click(function() {
    let player = this.getAttribute('data-selection'),
        ai = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'][Math.round(Math.random() * 2)],
        outcome = player === ai ? 'TIE' :
          ((player === 'rock' && ai === 'scissors') ||
          (player === 'paper' && ai === 'rock') ||
          (player === 'scissors' && ai === 'paper')) ? 'WIN' :
          'LOST';
        
    $('.chant').hide();
    $('.chant.player').text(player).fadeIn();
    $('.chant.ai').text(ai).fadeIn('slow');
    $('.chant.outcome').text(outcome).fadeIn(3000);
  });
```

```html
<div class="selections">
  <button data-selection="rock">&#128507;</button>
  <button data-selection="paper"></button>
  <button data-selection="scissors">&#9986;</button>
</div>
<h2 class="chant player"></h2>
<h2 class="chant ai"></h2>
<h2 class="chant outcome"></h2>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you want to make absolutely sure that they fade in in sequence, [.fadeIn()](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/) allows for an `on complete` callback, so you could nest them:

```
$('.chant.player').text(player).fadeIn(function() {
  $('.chant.ai').text(ai).fadeIn('slow', function() {
    $('.chant.outcome').text(outcome).fadeIn(3000);
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with the document.ready function and used the .fadeIn .fadeOut effects. I hid each h2 element individually in my html and came to this solution. The only issue I'm having now is the screen expands and moves some elements when the script is ran.

```js
//Displays the chant 'Rock Paper Scissors Shoot!' after one of the buttons is clicked
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('#rock').fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
    $('#paper').delay(2000).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
    $('#scissors').delay(4000).fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
    $('#shoot').delay(6000).fadeIn(500);
  });
});
```

```css
@import
  url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Big+Shoulders+Stencil+Display:wght@100&display=swap');

*{
  font-family: "Big Shoulders Stencil Display", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: #A80289;
}

.game {
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.selections {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

button {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

.selection {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 100ms;
}

.selection:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.chant {
  border: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#rock {
  position: relative;
  left: 49.4%
}

#paper {
  position: relative;
  left: 49%;
}

#scissors {
  position: relative;
  left: 48.14%;
}

#shoot {
  position: relative;
  left: 48.7%;
}

.winner {
  margin: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, .2fr);
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.winner-score {
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.result-selection {
  opacity: .5;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.result-selection.winner {
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

/*Media Queries*/
  /*Tablets and smaller*/
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .game {
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }

  .selection {
    font-size: 40px;
  }

  .chant {
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }

  #rock {
    position: relative;
    left: 48%
  }

  #paper {
    position: relative;
    left: 47.62%;
  }

  #scissors {
    position: relative;
    left: 45.7%;
  }

  #shoot {
    position: relative;
    left: 46.5%;
  }

  .winner {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

  /*Mobile*/
@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .game {
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }

  .selection {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .chant {
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
  }

  #rock {
    position: relative;
    left: 47.26%
  }

  #paper {
    position: relative;
    left: 46.27%;
  }

  #scissors {
    position: relative;
    left: 43.19%;
  }

  #shoot {
    position: relative;
    left: 45%;
  }

  .winner {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" {IF CLASSES}class="classes"{/IF}>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="game">
      <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="selections">
      <button class="selection" data-selection="rock">&#128507;</button>
      <button class="selection" data-selection="paper"></button>
      <button class="selection" data-selection="scissors">&#9986;</button>
    </div>
    <h2 class="chant" hidden id="rock">Rock</h2>
    <h2 class="chant" hidden id="paper">Paper</h2>
    <h2 class="chant" hidden id=scissors>Scissors</h2>
    <h2 class="chant" hidden id="shoot">Shoot!</h2>
    <div class="winner">
      <div>
        Player
        <span class="winner-score" data-your-score>0</span>
      </div>
      <div data-final-column>
        Computer
        <span class="winner-score" data-computer-score>0</span>
      </div>
<!--
      <div class="result-selection winner">&#9986;</div>
      <div class="result-selection"></div>
-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```